# RefineryCMS + Extend the routes for image upload custom methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, refinerycms

In my refinery-cms application, I have added one custom method for image upload.

No Issue is like when I define the routes in GemFile Code, it works.

But I am not getting the way to extend my routes present in my application for that custom method.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
```

match 'URL' => 'Controller_with_scope#action_name', :as => :action_name

end

This will load ur custom routes before application